# Вместо того(,) чтобы

Tags: пунктуация

"В этом случае, вместо того чтобы увольнять работника, нужно позаботиться о повышении его квалификации."
Верно ли стоит запятая перед оборотом "вместо того чтобы"? Или же запятая должна стоять перед "чтобы"? Как понять, в каких случаях и где ставить запятую?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подчинительный союз **вместо того чтобы** является сложным. Если придаточное предложение соединено с главным при помощи сложного подчинительного союза, то запятая ставится один раз: перед союзом, если придаточное предложение следует за главным или находится внутри его, и после всего придаточного предложения, если оно предшествует главному. Однако в зависимости от смысла, логического подчеркивания придаточного предложения, наличия в предложении определенных лексических элементов сложный союз может распадаться на две части: первая входит в состав главного предложения как соотносительное слово, а вторая выполняет роль союза; в этих случаях запятая ставится только перед второй частью сочетания (т.е. перед союзом *что, как, чтобы*).

Чаще не расчленяется сложный подчинительный союз, если придаточное предложение предшествует главному, например: *С тех пор как я женился, я уж от тебя прежней любви не вижу* (А.Н. Островский).

К условиям расчленения сложного союза относятся:
1)наличие перед союзом отрицания не, например: *Пастухов сошелся с Цветухиным **не** потому, что тяготел к актерам* (Федин);
2)наличие перед союзом усилительных, ограничительных и других частиц, например: *Наташа в эту зиму в первый раз начала серьезно петь и в **особенности** оттого, что Денисов восторгался ее пением* (Л. Толстой); *Водитель **как раз** для того, чтобы люди схлынули, застопорил машину против калитки* (Фадеев);
3)наличие перед союзом вводного слова, например: *...Все это имеет для меня неизъяснимую прелесть, **может быть**, оттого, что я уже не увижу их...* (Гоголь); 
4)включение первой части (соотносительного слова) в ряд однородных членов, например: *Ромашов же краснел до настоящих слез от своего бессилия и растерянности, и от боли за оскорбленную Шурочку, и **оттого**, что ему сквозь оглушительные звуки кадрили не удавалось вставить ни одного слова...* (Куприн).

В вашем примере придаточное предложение (вместо того чтобы увольнять работника) находится внутри главного (в этом случае нужно позаботиться о повышении его квалификации). Никаких показаний к расчленению сложного союза **вместо того чтобы** нет. Знаки препинания стоят правильно.