# Запятая в сложном союзе "вместо того чтобы"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в предложении "Но вместо того (,) чтобы презирать зарубежных бунтовщиков, советская молодежь сделала их примером для подражания"?

И корректно ли выделить конструкцию следующим образом: "Но*, вместо того чтобы презирать зарубежных бунтовщиков*, советская молодежь сделала их примером для подражания"?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вместо того(,) чтобы](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/50265/%d0%92%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b)

Comment: Нет, не дубликат. Данный вопрос шире, он касается не только союза "вместо того чтобы", но и запятой после *но*.

Answer (score 1):

**Но, вместо того чтобы презирать зарубежных бунтовщиков, советская молодежь сделала их примером для подражания.**

Составной союз *вместо того чтобы* **в данном случае** не должен расчленяться. На эту тему можно найти статью на Грамоте на ответы на нашем сайте:
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach3
[Вместо того(,) чтобы](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4087/%d0%92%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b)
[Вместо того(,) чтобы](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/50265/%d0%92%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b)
["вместо того(,) чтобы " - расчленяется или нет?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/418718/%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%87%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82)
[О составном союзе "вместо того чтобы"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/418735/%d0%9e-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%8e%d0%b7%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b)

*Но* в данном случае относится к главной части (Но советская молодежь сделала их примером для подражания), поэтому отделяется от придаточной части запятой.