# Запятая между частями составного союза в предложении с несколькими придаточными

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп, сложное-предложение, придаточное-предложение

*Когда собеседник рассказывает о том, чем он сейчас занимается, вместо того(,) чтобы молча кивать, подумай, чем ты можешь ему помочь.*

Волнует:

1. Постановка/отсутствие запятой и основание решения.
2. Как в таких случаях ещё и избежать двусмысленности? Чтобы не получилось, что собеседник сейчас чем-то занимается, вместо того чтобы молча кивать.

**Дополнение**

Мой вопрос отличается от других вопросов по теме составного союза «вместо того(,) чтобы». В моём случае ситуация осложняется нахождением союза на границе сложноподчинённого предложения, причём союз располагается по соседству с придаточным, относящемуся к другой части предложения. Сложные отношения связи между частями предложения плюс проблема с возникновением двусмысленности вынудила меня создать отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вместо того(,) чтобы](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4087/%d0%92%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b)

Comment: Обратитесь с запросом «того(,) чтобы» к Поиску по сайту

Comment: Условия расчленения составного союза есть здесь: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach3

Comment: Во избежание двусмысленности, можно перенести в самый конец часть, присоединяемую через "вместо того...".

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы избежать двусмысленности, предложение желательно перестроить. Например так:

**Когда собеседник рассказывает о том, чем он сейчас занимается, не ограничивайся тем, чтобы молча кивать, а подумай, чем ты можешь ему помочь.**

Примечание: думаю, правильнее не противопоставлять "кивание" и "думание".

Дополнение. Можно просто добавить `то`; будет не очень складно, но понятно:
**Когда собеседник рассказывает о том, чем он сейчас занимается, `то`, вместо того чтобы молча кивать, подумай, чем ты можешь ему помочь.**

Comment: В вашем первом варианте перед «подумай» нужно поставить тире: имеет место противопоставление, пропущен союз «а».

Comment: Насчет тире не уверен, я просто добавил *а*.

Comment: Также я не видел такого составного союза "когда..., то...".

Comment: Когда...то. Вот лишь некоторые примеры из Нацкорпуса: Когда группы достаточно сблизятся, то между ними может пройти химическая реакция..." [Сергей Алексеев. Превращения цепей. Премия для молодого ученого-теоретика (2003) // «Известия», 2003.02.20]  Когда в одних руках сосредоточены бизнес-функция и контрольно-надзорная, то последнюю легко применить для уничтожения конкурентов [Павел Иванов. Ключ к правовой экономике. Популярные хроники непопулярного закона // «Воздушно-космическая оборона», 2003]

Comment: Когда я давал показания, то видел этого Иванычева. [Елена Лория. Владимира Сухомлина могли убить офицеры милиции (2003) // «Известия», 2003.01.12]  Поэтому, когда звучат обвинения, что Зорькин поддержал Верховный совет, то это не соответствует истине. [Светлана Сухова. Конституция и революция (2003) // «Итоги», 2003.03.04]